# Rmarkdown iframes and Character Encodings

Tags: r, iframe, encoding, knitr, r-markdown

I would like my Rmarkdown to include an iframe.

I have tried:

`````
---
title: "DASAtimeVis"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
````
### Latest News
```{r}
knitr::include_url("https://apnews.com/",height="400px")
```
`````

When this command threw an `Error in enc2utf8(x) : argument is not a character vector` I sought out how R encodes characters. The `Encoding` function sets encodings of characters as ascii, UTF08, etc..  Therefore, I tried things like this :

```
u<-( "https://apnews.com") 
Encoding(u)
Encoding(u)<-"bytes"
knitr::include_url(u,height="400px")
```

Only to receive the same error.

How can an iframe be included in Rmarkdown?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. [Is everything up-to-date?](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: I ran `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`
and this did not help...   :(

Comment: @YihuiXie on second thought I am not certain running `update.packages` is a good idea as it reset so many of mine that I had a number re-installs to complete before my other code would function again....